# double vs twice the normal price

Tags: adverbs

Do double and twice have the same meaning? Can they be used interchangeably?

> I'll pay you *double* the normal price if you drive me there at 2 in the morning.

> I'll pay you *twice* the normal price if you drive me there at 2 in the morning.

Comment: Yes, *in this narrow context*, they have the same meaning and can be used interchangeably, but change the context just a bit, and they have different meanings: "*I'll pay you **double***" doesn't mean the same thing as, "*I'll pay you **twice***".

Comment: Thank you. What's the difference between your two sentences?

Comment: "*I'll pay you double...*" means price x2. "*I'll pay you twice*" means I will pay you on two separate occasions. It means nothing about the price, so it could mean two half payments, two full payments, or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this narrow context, they have the same meaning and can be used interchangeably, but change the context just a bit, and they have different meanings: "I'll pay you double" doesn't mean the same thing as, "I'll pay you twice"

"I'll pay you double..." means price ×2. "I'll pay you twice" means I will pay you on two separate occasions. It means nothing about the price, so it could mean two half payments, two full payments, or anything else.